# Add title for sections in a view

Tags: views

so I am trying to create a view via Drupal 8 Structure->Views, and I am setting up this view to display certain shops in certain areas, I would like titles above each type of location of shops, so I would like u.s.a stores to have a title, and canada stores to have a title, is this possible in the view creator? for example:[image]

Or should I create separate views, then sort in the twig files, example stores - can, stores - usa

Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to group and sort the results by type or by country?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a title for each type of view, I would click the add button for a "header" then click on Global text and enter in the Title you want for that view.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

Also, if you are looking to put in a title for each entry you could look into making that a content type that the view pulls from. It can pull the Title of each entity.